# How to return `uint []` from `unsigned int *` using swig

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I have to wrap the following c++ function:

```
class Foo {
  unsigned int *getVector3();
};
```

The member function `getVector3`, returns a (fixed) 3D array, eg `[1,2,3]`. How should I use [`arrays_csharp.i`](https://github.com/swig/swig/commits/master/Lib/csharp/arrays_csharp.i) for a return type ? The documentation only describes for input parameters:

- [22.4 C# Arrays](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_arrays)

In my case the return type is always a fixed size array (of 3 elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer, although it's not entirely satisfactory in my view. That's mostly limited by my knowledge of C# though, so you can probably make it work better than I can.

I don't think arrays_csharp is what you're looking for here. It seems to be about pinning memory so it can be used as input to a function, but in your scenario you've got memory already allocated that you'd like to work with.

That's fairly easy (and for a 3D vector pretty cheap), using System.InteropServices.Marshal normally. So I put together a few typemaps using that which does what you want:

```
%module test
%typemap(csout,excode=SWIGEXCODE) unsigned *getVector {
    global::System.IntPtr cPtr = $imcall;$excode
    int[] tmp = new int[3];
    // I have no idea why Marshal.Copy does not seem to have any support for unsigned types...
    global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(cPtr, tmp, 0, 3);
    // There is probably a better way to go from int[3] -> uint[3], but it is not obvious to me
    return new $typemap(cstype, $*1_type)[3]{($typemap(cstype, $*1_type))tmp[0],($typemap(cstype, $*1_type))tmp[1],($typemap(cstype, $*1_type))tmp[2]};
}

%typemap(cstype) unsigned *getVector "$typemap(cstype, $*1_type)[]"

%inline %{
unsigned *getVector() {
  static unsigned arr[3] = {1,2,3};
  return arr;
}
%}
```

A few notes though:

- `$typemap(cstype, $*1_type)` is a fancy way of saying find me the C# type corresponding to my C element type. I tend to try and avoid explicitly writing types in typemaps as it makes things more generic.
- Having said that `Marshal.Copy` only seems to work with signed rather than unsigned array types, for reasons I can't quite figure out. And I can't see an automatic way to find the corresponding signed type for an unsigned one, so I did have to explicitly write `int[]`
- I'm not sure that signed -> unsigned casting is actually well defined behaviour in C#. Maybe this won't work properly for values where the last bit is set. You can work around that by increasing the size of the `int` type for `tmp`. (E.g. use `int64` instead of `int32`, but that's not pretty)
- There ought to be a better way to cast a whole array than what I've done, but I don't know the C# language all that well.

That said this is sufficient that I can run the following program (with Mono) and get the output expected

```
public class runme {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    uint[] arr = test.getVector();
    System.Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
    System.Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);
    System.Console.WriteLine(arr[2]);
  }
}
```

We could do a bunch more work to make this generic (i.e. other size vectors, other datatypes `int16[4]`, etc.) if that was useful.